# Copying from s3 bucket to redshift I get system messages in raw_line of stl_load_errosrs

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a tab-separated text file in an s3 bucket which I would like to upload to redshift.

My redshift query looks like this:

```
COPY rk_test_tab
    from 's3://my_bucket/my_file'
    iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/XXX'
    IGNOREHEADER 1
    BLANKSASNULL
    EMPTYASNULL
    MAXERROR 10
    DELIMITER '\t'
;
```

A raw line from the data file read via Python looks like this:

```
b'1008498338\t1.0\t1\t1\tCBDT\n'
```

This fails with the message `Load into table 'rk_test_tab' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.`

When I look at the `stl_load_errors` the `raw_line` field is very odd:
`[GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 430.9, Avg: 430.9, Max: 431.0, Diff: 0.2]`
(Double checked there are no lines like this in my file)

The `err_reason` is given as `Delimiter not found`.

If I remove the `IGNOREHEADER 1` line, I get an error because my headers don't match the expected data field types, but crucially the `raw_line` does match that in the the file, so the file in the s3 bucket is getting through.

So my question is: what can be going wrong such that Redshift is trying to read in what look like system info messages (Garbage collection?).

Comment: Depending on client quering redshift you may try another backslash: '\\t' - worked in our case. Can you add the correspondig result from STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL as well?

Comment: Thanks I'm away from computer just now but will try that later.

Comment: The STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL table is empty

Comment: I tried various versions of the tab character formatting. In the end I used a workaround, read in the file from s3, write it back to s3 replacing '\t' for ',' then use the `COPY` command as above using `DELIMITER ','`. 
I'm not entering this as an answer as I'd still like a method to load the native file direct from s3.